# Crystal report batch/massive print

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I'm facing a problem while trying to print several files from my web aplication.

This is the issue:

We have a gridview with several rows, the user selects the rows he wants to print (usually 2xx or a bit more). Each row has a code, which is already printed on the paper so this is the expected result:

Paper       |   Row Printed

1              |   1

2              |   2

3              |   3

4              |   4

5              |   5

However, this is how we are getting the prints

Paper       |   Row Printed

1              |   1

2              |   2

3              |   4

4              |   5

5              |   7

*The numbers are only for reference, this usually dont happens with the first ones

I suspect that there may be some rows being lost in the network (since its a network printer). What i would like to try is to send all of the documents in 1 call instead of one by one. I've been searching, but so far nothing. I'd really appreciate some help.

Here is a snippet of the code we use to print:

```
'gridview rows loop

    'validations & some operations

    CrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1,False,0,0)

'next row
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greetings

Oscar

pd: sorry if my english isn't that good, its not my native language